# What is MNLI-(m/mm)?

Tags: terminology, transformer, bert, natural-language-understanding

I came across the term **MNLI-(m/mm)** in Table 1 of the paper [BERT: Pre-training of Deep Bidirectional Transformers for Language Understanding](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf). I know what MNLI stands for, i.e. Multi-Genre Natural Language Inference, but I'm just unsure about the **-(m/mm)** part.

I tried to find some information about this in the paper [GLUE: A Multi-Task Benchmark and Analysis Platform for Natural Language Understanding](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07461.pdf), but this explained only the basic Multi-Genre Language Inference concept. I assume that the **m/mm** part was introduced later, but this doesn't make any sense because the BERT paper appeared earlier.

It would be nice if someone knows this or has a paper that explains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I have found out it stands for a different type of task.

I have found it here. https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/text_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=kTCFado4IrIc

It states that mnli-mm stands for the mismatched version of MNLI
That means that the mnli-m would mean matched version of MNLI

On the following link is more about the MNLI: [https://cims.nyu.edu/~sbowman/multinli/](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Esbowman/multinli/)

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.